# button to receipt not working on live dashboard, does work on print preview screen

Tags: dashboard, pdf, receipts

something strange is happening at our site. The button to print a PDF receipt is not working on the live dashboard (within the site), it is working though on the print preview of the same page. On the live dashboard the links disappears from the HTML code.

HTML code from the live dashboard:
[image: Code from live dashboard]

HTML code from print preview of the same page:
[image: code from same page print preview]

Comment: Evelien, can you please specify which version of CiviCRM you are using, what CMS you are using it with and if there is local customization? That will certainly help folks to help you :-) Alvast bedankt!

Comment: sorry, we are on civicrm 4.6.10 with wordpress 4.4

Comment: with hardly any local customization. The only thing we did is some custom CSS and creating custom templates for PDF-files using the civicrm interface. No customization on the core files.

Comment: right now we are on civicrm 4.6.16 with wordpress 4.5.2 and the problem still exists

Comment: old issue, but still a problem. In the meantime we switched servers and we are now on WordPress 4.7.3 with Civicrm 4.7.18. Does this work at any other website?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is working at all of my local installs and some of our customers use this button to actually print invoices using CiviCRM 4.6.24